# Dynamic data for winforms

Tags: winforms, scaffolding

i have played around with dynamic data website. is there something similar for winforms.
if there isn't anything out there for doing the same with winforms than the question would be why not? we have a massive ERP application that we want to migrate from AS400 to .Net
Winform application. my initial thoughts were to have all the maintenances be as simple as Dynamic Data Website project.

Comment: Just voted down a lot of the answers here.  This guy is simply asking "Is there something like dynamic data for winforms?" and most of the answers involve a misunderstanding of what dynamic data is and its feature set or completely missing the point and recommending rolling his oown.

Comment: voted up(except my own) Helpful attempts when there is a lack of clarity and presence from the Questioner, is NOT a down-votable offense.  IMHO.  Though if I had noticed that the question was from Dec 6 and that he has 0% acceptance I probably wouldn't have taken time to try and help in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that WPF would be a better starting point then WinForms, as it has support for style to say how item of data are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Data makes it easy to edit your DB on the web.  For desktop (and web) apps take a look at the new Microsoft LightSwitch:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/lightswitch/gg441300

LightSwitch doesn't use Windows Forms.  Rather it creates a Silverlight App that can run both on the desktop and the web.  Pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic data is using the routing functionality of the MVC framework. In Windows forms we don't have this approach of fetching data with URLs from a server.
I am not sure how this model could fit into Windows forms.

I think it's pretty hard to create something like dynamic data for Windows Forms.
My biggest concern is here, once you created that Framework, how do you configure it? I mean if you want to change 1 form to be a bit different than the others :-)

I think its better to generate Forms for the various tables in the Database context, using a powerful Grid control from one of the big vendors. And then you can configure those.

**Remember** this is a different approach then the dynamic data one, where no code is generated before compile time

Comment: Have a look at DevExpress eXpressApp and nconstruct
Maybe they go into the direction you are looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you don't see something like this in winform applications is because it's much easier to store a HTML page inside a database and then display it on the screen formatted properly when using a web application because your browser knows how to format the HTML.

You would have to, stored in the database, know where each label and field would go on the form in some sort of co-ordinates fashion (or you could use a layout 3rd party control) but the amount of work that would take might be tedious to do properly.

The dynamic data website I worked on did not take input from the user.  It only displayed different web pages to the user and allowed the admin person to easily make changes to the content.  If you wanted a user to beable to save data then that would even be more complex because you have to worry about validation, required fields, etc.

If you have lots of users that need to see different information based on their access level then I would just suggest having a table in the database that tells the system whether or not they should see the field on the form.  Then use a 3rd party layout panel to format the visible fields.

my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

As much as Dynamic Data looks simple and cheap enough to access a database it wouldn't work for an ERP system anyways. Business systems are more than moving data between database and the user interface, they require business rule actions when saving data and while retrieving the may require some massaging to ensure meaningful presentation of storage optimized data.

If you still like to pursue this option it would be very easy to create an application that is build on top of Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a Dynamic-Data-alike, but (having written one before, years ago, for ASP) I don't actually think it would be *that* hard, particularly with WPF and its templating support.

Actually if you were really clever you could probably 'borrow' the backend from Dynamic Data, and just reimplement the UI as WPF.

Would make a fun little project actually.

Alternative answer: Use Microsoft Access. No really.
Alternative answer #2: So why not just use Dynamic Data then?