# Code-Generating a Winforms form from a C# POCO Class

Tags: c#, winforms, code-generation

Is there some open source code already written out there somewhere that will accept a class with properties and validation attributes, and output a Windows form with controls that correspond to those properties?

Examples:

```
public bool IsRed { get; set; }
```

produces a checkbox with an `Is Red?` label.

```
public int NumberOfDays { get; set; }
```

produces a text box with a label called `Number of Days` and restricts input to numeric characters only.

```
[Required]
public Color Color { get; set; }
```

where Color is an enum of the form

```
public enum Color
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}
```

produces a combo box with the list populated with `Red` `Green` and `Blue`, and makes it required.

Ideally, the generated code includes a method that accepts an instance of my class and prepopulates the controls in the winform with the values in the properties of my instance.  Correspondingly, another method saves the existing values in the controls to an instance of my class.

Is there something like that available?

---

Please note: I am *not* looking for:

1. An ORM or DAL
2. A generalized tool like CodeSmith, unless it's free and open-source
3. WPF or ASP.NET code, it needs to be Winforms
4. NetTiers or any similar type of complete application framework, unless I can parse out the small part of it that applies specifically to this scenario.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345915/dynamic-data-for-winforms

Comment: Am I right, that you are looking for a `PropertyGrid` like thing? Well one that decomposes into controls?

Comment: Something like that.  I'm building editors for a packetized file structure, and it's got a non-trivial number of different data structures in it that require editors, so it would be nice to just blow out some windows forms from those data structures (for which I already have corresponding classes or structs) as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 'quite easy' to extract the functionality of the `PropertyGrid` into your own hosted controls, but that would only cover half your requirement. At a minimum, read up on `TypeConverter`, `TypeDescriptor` and `PropertyDescriptor`.

Also have a look at: [codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/xacc_propertygrid.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/xacc_propertygrid.aspx), this basically exposes the `PropertyGrid`'s functionality to a web page, but it will give you some ideas.

I know this is not a complete answer, but should point one in the right direction to write/author such a tool.

It would be nice if such a scaffolding tool existed for WinForms :)